# How to access gwt:property properties from code?

Tags: java, html, gwt

For example, if I have

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="variable=value"/>
```

in my host HTML, how can I access it from java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you can get this specific meta directly, but with the following GWT code you can get the content:

```
    final NodeList<Element> metas = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("meta");

    for (int i = 0; i < metas.getLength(); i++) {
        final MetaElement m = MetaElement.as(metas.getItem(i));

        if ("gwt:property".equals(m.getName())) {
            //do something with content: m.getContent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey, I realize this is an old post, but what if I want to get the "class" property of a <tr> ? Do I still use MetaElement or should I use TableRowElement ? I ask because the latter doesn't have getContent()